# Aurelia http post returning 404

Tags: javascript, http-status-code-404, aurelia

Hi im having a problem with post in aurelia. My /api/user/loginCtrl.php returns 404 error, i was doing some tests and with get it returns 2oo. but i need this with post because is login, can u help me pls? I cant find the bug

```
var loginData = {
           userLogin:    validator.trimString(this.userLogin),
           userPassword: validator.trimString(this.userPassword),
           uuid:         validator.getUUID()
       };


       var httpObj = new HttpClient().configure(x => {
           x.withHeader('Content-Type', 'application/json');
           //x.withHeader("Content-Type", "application/x-www-form-urlencoded");
       });

       httpObj.post('../api/user/loginCtrl.php',loginData).then(response => {
       //this.phones = response.content;
       });
```

Comment: try using an absolute path instead of  `../api/...`

Comment: Are you sure that the loginCtrl accepts post?